# Error message: grub2 is obsoleted by grub2

Tags: rhel, yum, grub2

If I run the following on RHEL 7 I see the error message shown:

```
[david@sycamore ~]$ sudo yum check
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
1:grub2-2.02-0.64.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by 1:grub2-2.02-0.64.el7.x86_64
Error: check all
```

How can I fix ?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well... I found this bugzilla about it: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1484042 I leary of uninstalling grub2, so I don't recommend that. However, keep an eye on the bugzilla for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Update the package grub2-2.02-0.64.el7.x86_64 to the next version that is 0.65